# How to create button with cut edges & rounded corners?

Tags: css, button, sass

I'm trying to create a button, according to design but have some trouble with rounding corners.

So I need to implement a button, which looks like this:
[Button view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCkqj.png)

I was trying to cut edges and set background color via `linear-gradient`, this way

```css
.button {
  width: 210px;
  height: 45px;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #389F96;
  background: 
  linear-gradient(-45deg, black, black, 30px, transparent 0px),
  linear-gradient(135deg, black, black, 30px, transparent 0px),
  linear-gradient(to bottom, #389F96, #46C1EE);
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Log in</button>
```

But in this case, `border-radius` make it round in an incorrect for me way

So I need to create a button like this (with rounded corners, cut edges, and with linear gradient border).

Is there some "easy way" to handle it?

Comment: Do you mean with a linear-gradient border, or is it the background of the button that is to have the linear-gradient?

Comment: @AHaworth  background of the button that is to have the linear-gradient.

Comment: pseudo-element + skew transformation

Comment: use [clip-path](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/)  to generate the shape you want.

Comment: @cloned clip-path doesn't allowed rounded/curved shapes (if it is not circle).

Comment: Not even if you use a svg as base? What about using [this method?](https://dev.to/afif/css-shapes-with-rounded-corners-56h)

Comment: @cloned Nice. Didn't know that. Interesting solution.

Answer (score 2):

If the button will always be the same size (as your CSS suggests), I would think about using SVG as background.

---

### Transform with pseudoelement

The most similar result I was able to achieve is based on [**Temani Afif's comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72258375/how-to-create-button-with-cut-edges-rounded-corners#comment-127661846):

```css
button {
  border: 0;
  padding: 1rem 6rem;
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-weight: bold;
}

button:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 4px 8px;
  transform: skewX(-30deg);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #389F96, #46C1EE);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<button>Log in!</button>
```

---

### Clip-path with SVG filter

Based on [**cloned comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72258375/how-to-create-button-with-cut-edges-rounded-corners#comment-127662207) and [Temani Afif's article](https://dev.to/afif/css-shapes-with-rounded-corners-56h) I achieved this:

```css
button {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  margin: 8px auto;
  display: block;
  filter:url(#round);
}

button > span {
  display: block;
  clip-path: polygon(10% 0, 100% 0, 90% 100%, 0% 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #389F96, #46C1EE);
  padding: 1rem 6rem;
}
```

```html
<svg style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
        <filter id="round">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="4" result="blur" />    
            <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9" result="goo" />
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>

<button>
  <span>
    Log in!
  </span>
</button>
```

---

*I have provided a solution based on your comments because you have not provided any answer. If you add it as an answer I will delete mine.*