# how to create a rounded corner for the picture(img tag) in clip-path polygon in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

in my design, I must create a polygon with a rounded corner. like this picture.[image]
I want the last part  (35% 100%), to create a border-radius of 30px.
how can I do it?
Thanks in advance for your guidance.

```css
img {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 35% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="assets/img/img-1.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: I'd go for `clip-path: path(...)` instead and use a path generator tool online to find the right path.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create button with cut edges & rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72258375/how-to-create-button-with-cut-edges-rounded-corners)

Answer (score 3):

Use skew to create such effect:

```css
.box {
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: auto;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: skewX(20deg);
}

.box img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  transform-origin: inherit;
  transform: skewX(-20deg); /* the opposite value here */
}

.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1069/500/200">
  </div>
</div>
```